# Unable to deploy contracts through truffle and local geth

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, truffle

I get the contracts through truffle to post but seems to hang, and getting the following warnings in the local geth. all seems ok, but contract does not Deploy.

```
Version: 1.7.2-stable
Git Commit: 1db4ecdc0b9e828ff65777fb466fc7c1d04e0de9
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9.2
Operating System: darwin
Truffle v4.0.1 (core: 4.0.1)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
```

The geth start up looks like following:

```
cat:Exchange user$ geth --rinkeby  --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin --unlock="0xMyAddressIsHere"
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 4 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 1035301 Engine: clique}"
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=4
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Loaded most recent local header          number=1209402 hash=520087…c9f686 td=2352904
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Loaded most recent local full block      number=1209402 hash=520087…c9f686 td=2352904
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1209402 hash=520087…c9f686 td=2352904
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=15 dropped=0
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=15 accounts=1
WARN [11-09|10:30:54] Blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled 
INFO [11-09|10:30:54] Starting P2P networking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under investigation we found that the  data block though appears to be ok in the terminal, had the above errors at the beginning, everything else appeared as normal.
To solve the issue we took to following steps to resolve the issue!

1. Back up the keystore in the network folder, example for rinkeby is shown here on the mac is located in `~/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/keystore/....`
2. Delete the Ethereum Folder
3. Run geth without the unlock parameter. and let it run example...

   `geth --rinkeby  --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin --fast --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*"`
4. When finished, stop geth, copy keyfile back then run with the unlock address
5. In your project folder, ensure to delete the `build` folder
6. Now try truffle migrate as follows:

   `npx truffle migrate --network rinkeby --reset`
7. should be working again.